# How to parse CSV that is passed as a parameter to a method

Tags: c#, linq, csv, memorystream

I have a string that contains content of CSV file.
I need to extract those values to my objects.
I don't get CSV from CSV file I receive it as a parameter (data).
And in [exmple they use file.csv](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library) to parse data.
I have tried to load it in `MemoryStream` but without luck.

```
public string methos(string data)
        {
            CsvFileDescription inputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
            {
                SeparatorChar = ',',
                FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
            };

            CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();

            MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(data));

            IEnumerable<Data datas=
            cc.Read<Data>(mStream, inputFileDescription);
```

Also I don't know if I pick good framework to parse CSV to custom objects but to me it's important that values can have commas and that framework can handle that.

Comment: Would you consider a custom CSV parser? For example, one where you explicitly map a position in the CSV to a property of your object? Or are you looking for something out there (3rd party) that does all this out the box?

Comment: I really don't care :) I just need to map values from CSV to my object and that's all. I do this for the first time and I need it fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQtoCSV only takes a StreamReader, not a stream.  Try this:

```
        using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(data)))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(mStream))
        {
            IEnumerable<Data> datas = cc.Read<Data>(reader, inputFileDescription);
        }
```